# how to handle the rotation or orientation in sencha?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

i'm working on extjs and came across one small problem it is , wen i resize the window everything works fine execpt for the disabled component....

before resizing the browser the disabled component looks fine
[image]

but after resizing the browser the panel and button behind the disabled css are exanding but the css does not 
[image]

here's the code:

```
    var topdetailpanel = new Ext.Panel(
    {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 1,
        disabled: false,
        monitorOrientation:true,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            pack: 'center',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        stretchX: true,
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            id: 'topdetailid',
            flex: 1,
            baseCls: 'round',
            monitorOrientation:true,
            stretchX: true,
            html: noresult,
            handler: function ()
            {
                window.location = 'DetailsPanel.html?type=' + typeval + '&event=' + eventval + '&price=' + priceval + '&free=0&pos=1'
            }}]
    });
    var bottomdetailpanel = new Ext.Panel(
    {
        flex: 1,
        id: 'ctrlBtn2',
        padding: 1,
        monitorOrientation:true,
        disabled: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            pack: 'center',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        stretchX: true,
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            flex: 1,
            monitorOrientation:true,
            id: 'bottomdetailid',
            baseCls: 'round',
            stretchX: true,
            html: noresult,
            handler: function ()
            {
                window.location = 'DetailsPanel.html?type=' + typeval + '&event=' + eventval + '&price=' + priceval + '&free=0&pos=2'
            }}]
    });
```

and for disabling i use :

bottomdetailpanel.setDisabled(true);

please help.......................

Thank you in advance.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey check this my friend faced the same issue..might be it will help you.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?115984-1.0-Form-Orientation-Change-incomplete-redraw

and in case you got the right answer somewhere  please post it back here..